# Simple SQL Select with all matches

Tags: sql, t-sql, relational-division

SQL question: I have table with two columns: `ProductId` and `CatId`

I want to select products that belong to all of the passed in `CatId`s.

For example this is my table:

```
ProductID        CatID
_____________________
1129                2
1129                3
1129                4
1130                2
1130                3
```

Now if I pass `2,3,4` the result should be `1129`.

If I pass `2,3` the result should be `1130` (not 1129, as it should belong to all of the CatIds passed, no less - no more)

Any idea how this can be achieved? `IN` with `AND` can not work. `IN` with `OR` will not serve the purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you passing in the ids to match? In a table valued parameter?

Comment: the key is to compare the results joined to you list with the results not joined to your list. getting the counts that match and are not zero.  Now the trick is writing that query...

Comment: no ... was trying with simple 'select' and 'where' clause with 'IN' ... not sure about table valued parameter thing (sorry not very good at sql at all :( )...

Comment: `+1` for adding sample records with desired result. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductID
FROM Table1 a
WHERE CatID IN (2,3)
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING COUNT(*) =
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM table1 b
          WHERE b.ProductID = a.ProductID
        ) AND 
        COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*includes 2 queries*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29aeb/5)

Comment: I think this should work, thanks for the Fiddle Demo thing. but i did not quite get you last line : "COUNT(*) = 2" I can not hard code that ? it should be dynamic. What do you think?

Comment: @aDev - Then use your own abilities to adapt the answer to your own development constraints???  It's a bit unfair to criticise an answer for not meeting a constraint that you don't mention in the question...   *[For example, insert the search parameters into a table variable, then use `WHERE CatID IN (SELECT id FROM @params)` and `AND COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @params)`]*

Comment: @Dems ... no idea what you meant here ... i didn't criticized ... was just asking ... am sorry if it felt bad ... :)

Comment: hey ... got it working ... in my test thing ... but i think i can implement it now ... thanks every one ... :)

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to see to how many of the categories the product belongs, by grouping by productId and then using `HAVING` to filter results with smaller subset of the categories

```
SELECT ProductID, COUNT(*) as c FROM table WHERE CatID IN(2,3,4) GROUP BY ProductID HAVING c = 3
```

Comment: i think this will output the `count` *not* the `id`.

Comment: you can add the id to the query as well :)